# UWP Push notifications in sleep mode

Tags: push-notification, notifications, uwp, toast

I used toast notification in my UWP app. The received notifications are in Raw format, so I parsed datas and I show a toast notification to alert user. For that I created a BackgroundTask to handle push notification and show the toast with this code:

```
var notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
notifier.Show(toast);
```

My implementation works well in all case except when the phone is in sleep mode. If the screen is lock but on, it works but when the screen is off the toast is not displayed.

I have no error because this issue does not appear when I launch app debugging.

Thanks for help

Comment: Since you've used push notification, why not just push a toast notification instead of raw notification?

Comment: Because in some cases, I don't have to display it. And I have to put up the same operation as existing on other platforms (Android and iOS)

Comment: I find that notification pop well when the smartphone is plugged to PC (without debug)